# Archive data older than DateTime (number of days) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a simple SQL query that I intend to put in a stored procedure to move old data from one table into an archive table. I know there are a number of ways to do this but here's what I've come up with:

```
DECLARE @days INT
SELECT Product.* INTO 
ProductArchive
WHERE OrderDateTimeUTC  = DATEADD(d, -(@days), GETUTCDATE())
```

The idea is to make this a SQL job to run at intervals.
Is there a 'best practice ' for this ? the primary table only ever has less than 2000 rows at any time.

Comment: Your code copies, not moves, data into a new table and will error if run more than once because the target table already exists. One of the many other methods to archive data is to create an archive table with the same schema as source and use DELETE with an `OUTPUT` clause to move rows periodically. The best practice is to specify an explict column list instead of `*`.

Comment: 2000 rows at max is not so much. So maybe, if you want just to archive them and this is no about a performance, you could add some flag `active` or `archived` which could be updated periodically and then used in views or in your application?

Answer (score 2):

OK so here's how I fixed my own issue i.e moving data from one table into an archive table and then deleting from the primary table. I've used a merge and a delete essentially along with a temp table.
I put the query in a stored procedure

```
DECLARE @days INT
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
  productid int NOT NULL
)
MERGE  ProductArchive as T 
USING (SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE OrderDateTimeUTC  = DATEADD(d, -(@days), GETUTCDATE()) 
) as S
ON T.productid = S.productid
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN 
INSERT 
(
--Insert 
)
VALUES
(
--values
)
--Delete from origin table
OUTPUT inserted.productid INTO @TempTable;
DELETE FROM Product WHERE productid 
IN(SELECT productid From @TempTable)
```